# iOS Universal Link does not executing delegate method

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I am trying to implement the universal links in one of our apps. Currently i am struggling that the needed AppDelegate methods been triggered:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler{

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options{
```

When i click on an link in safari the app will open but does not runs the method so i can handle and route the user.

Here are my current setttings / setup:

- App Identifier has the "Associated Domains" capabilities enabled.
- In XCode i also added the associalted domains capabilites and add the domain entry "applinks:example.google.com" (i use our domain ;-))
- The entitlements file is created, filled with the applink domain and setup in the Build settings
- Our apple-app-site-association file is already in apples cdn

My problem is that the app will be opened but does not running the needed method. Do you have any solution for that?